# Which .net builtin functions use the params keyword?

Tags: c#, arrays, c++-cli, parameters

I am explaining the purpose and usage of the C# `params` (C++CLI `...array`) keyword to my colleague and wanted to show him some functions of .net that make use of it. But right know I don't remember any.

For those who want to answer: Feel free to list as many as you know. But I would be happy with one already.

Comment: A canonical example would be Console.WriteLine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @jeroenh Oh, yes, the probably most used of all. If you had added an answer instead of a comment, you'd have had the 1st upvote already.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: If that info was available elsewhere, I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.Format("It is now {0}.", DateTime.Now)
Console.WriteLine("It is now {0}.", DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: Interesting question to come out of retirement for :P

Comment: Technically the cases with < 3 arguments are actually separate overloads that don't use the `params` bit :P